# Create X509Certificate2 from PEM files ASP .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, x509certificate2

I'm having trouble generating a X509Certificate2 object from 2 .PEM files. I have 2 different files with the extension .PEM for both, and their content is

> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

> {text}

> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

for one and

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

> {text}

> -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"

for the other.

Problem: I need to generate a X509Certificate2 object using that.

I have tried to deliver an array []base64 but it has not worked.

I have tried to deliver you the file path, the file name, but I think you need the contents of .PEM.

I have searched but I have not gotten anything.

I have also not managed to transform the file to PFX.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with some information link or some code example, since I have not achieved anything.

Here I leave my last code used:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate2()
{
    X509Certificate2 myCert = null;
    try
    {
        var pemCert = CargarCertificado();
        var pemPass = CargarLlave();
        myCert = new X509Certificate2(pemCert, pemPass);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return myCert;
}

public static SecureString CargarLlave()
{
    SecureString resp = new SecureString();
    string path = @"C:\PRIVATE_KEY.pem";
    var text = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    resp = new NetworkCredential("", text).SecurePassword;
    return resp;
}

public static Byte[] CargarCertificado()
{
    Byte[] bytes;
    string path = @"C:\CERTIFICATE_REQUEST.pem";
    var text = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "").Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "");
    bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
    return bytes;
}
```

The exception now says:

> The requested object cannot be found.

**stack trace:**

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
> en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[] rawData)
> en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
> en System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, SecureString password)

Comment: `BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST` is the marker for a PKCS#10 certification request... not for an actual X.509 public key certificate (there's no issuer and it's missing a lot of useful extensions that the issuing-CA is supposed to fill in).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I understand that what I have is a CSR and I also have a private key that allows me to decrypt the file, but I still don't understand how to transform that into a X509Certificate2. I know the problem is because the file format shouldn't be a csr, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: It's sort of an apples and oranges thing.  It's kind of like "I bookmarked the webpage for the 2021 Ferrari 812GTS, but can't find the car in my driveway."  You send a CSR to a certificate authority, they produce a certificate, then you can load that.  If you're trying to be the certificate authority then that's a much bigger question, and the answer is more or less "it's not possible using just the types built in to the framework"

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is much clearer to me